# Can I create a dataframe from few 1d arrays as columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Is it possible to create a dataframe from few 1d arrays and place them as columns?
If I create a dataframe from 1 1d array everything is ok:

```
arr1 = np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
arr1_arr2_df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr1, index=None, columns=None) 
arr1_arr2_df
Out: 
    0
0  11
1  12
2  13
3  14
4  15
```

But If make a datafreme form 2 arrays they are placed is rows:

```
arr1 = np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
arr2 = np.array([21, 22, 23, 24, 25])
arr1_arr2_df = pd.DataFrame(data=(arr1,arr2), index=None, columns=None)
arr1_arr2_df
Out: 
    0   1   2   3   4
0  11  12  13  14  15
1  21  22  23  24  25
```

I know that I can achieve it by using transpose:

```
arr1_arr2_df = arr1_arr2_df.transpose()
arr1_arr2_df
Out: 
    0   1
0  11  21
1  12  22
2  13  23
3  14  24
4  15  25
```

But is it possible to get it from the start?

Comment: what about zip? `arr1_arr2_df = pd.DataFrame(data=(zip(arr1,arr2)), index=None, columns=None)`

Comment: since we r in the mood : ```pd.DataFrame(dict(enumerate((arr1,arr2))))``` . But really, ```zip``` does the job succinctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
arr1_arr2_df = pd.DataFrame(data={0:arr1,1:arr2})
```